# Inserting values into two different databases dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert two values into my table using SQL: The members ID and the centre they attend. The centre table takes the Centre ID and the Members ID and links them together.

The problem is i am trying to do this via php when I add a new member (so while creating the member ID). The idea is that using the form you create the member (and an ID will be created) and add it to the members table then at the same time you insert the centre (integer) and that members ID into the Centre table

```
PK (auto Int)                (Linked to the members table)
CentreID         CAddress          memberID
  13                10                 1
  14                11                 2
  15                12                 3
```

I hope that makes some sense. I am having some trouble explaining it as i cant quite get my head around how you would do this either.

Here is a picture of my interface which is supposed to perform the operation.
[image]

Comment: Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID that was assigned to the new member, and use that when inserting into the `Centre` table.

Comment: Are you doing this in a PHP script or in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with phpMyAdmin; that screenshot isn't from phpMyAdmin and the question doesn't seem related. Is there a reason for the tag?

Comment: Its because i am working with Phpmyadmin. Though in this particular case i guess it has no baring which DBMS i am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert into Center table then use mysql_last inert id which you can use as hidden field in the next form and then save at the time of post.